# ScrollView in adjust resize

Tags: java, android

The buttons are in the linear layout
How to **scroll** only in adjust resize mode?

Because the buttons in the adjust resize after the keyboard is raised

I do not know English language. Excuse me

Answer (score 0):

go to AndroidManifest and add this line to the current activity

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: i'm not sure if i understood clearly you're question